# Alternative Java or C# UI libraries targeted at gaming

Tags: c#, java, user-interface, xna

Other than AWT, Swing, SWT (Java) - are there any good open source Java or C# UI libraries around?  In particular, libs intended or at least usable for strategy gaming dev?  (The visual appearance of the UI would need to be highly dynamic and easy to re-skin obviously.)  Engines or "frameworks" which include this functionality are valid answers as well (of course I even more doubt that those exist).

As far as I can tell - there's not a single thing like this out there. Anyone able to prove me wrong?

Comment: You're more likely to get good answers for this over at gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: for .net try XNA http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/19/building-killer-games-using-net-and-xna-game-studio-express.aspx

Comment: There's a gamedev.stackexchange.com?  Hate to be a complainer but ugh, that's too much.  Yet another SO-clone type site I have to create an account for?  I hope they do some single-sign on thing soon.

Comment: @Crusader, It's part of the whole stackexchange thing, that SO is also a part of, so you get single sign on over at gamedev :)

Comment: Wow. Is SO becoming a points-based pissing contest where people can't resist using their "powers", just because they can? The close-monkeys who needlessly closed this perfectly constructive and useful query should get a life and spend some more time trying to help people actually find answers to their questions--you know--the actual objective of this website? Whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Java, but for C# I would look at either XNA or Unity to start out with.